# Razor template editor doesn't like my Knockout attr binding syntax

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, razor-2

I have an Knockout attr binding that is working perfectly well:

```
<a data-bind="attr: { href: 'Action?destination=' + '@Model.Property' + '&entityId=' + Id }">Select</a>
```

However, the syntax highlighting in Visual Studio is throwing an 'Unterminated String Constant' error once any model property in inserted into the href string.

I've experimented with '@()' and '@:', but nothing seems to make the editor happy.

Comment: Does the code renders correctly and works in the browser? If yes then you should not care about the VS error message... the Razor intelisense is still not 100% correct. By the way which version of VS are you using? 2010? 2012? Vanilia or with Resharper/CodeRush/etc?

Comment: @nemesv: I'm using 2012 Update 2 vanilla.  The code renders correctly and works just fine across multiple browsers.  I just figure the VS error will cause concern for some of our other programmers or markup developers...

Comment: Have you tried assigning the whole `href` to a local variable beforehand, and then using that to put the value in, so that you don't have any single quotes?

Comment: Why are you using knockout for something that can be acheived with just a regular html link? (Hmtl.ActionLink helper)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where I wanted to pass controller action URLs (provided by the `UrlHelper` instance of the Razor view) to my viewmodel functions to be used later in jQuery AJAX calls.

The following markup works in the browser, but gives syntax highlighting in Visual Studio:

```
<button data-bind="click: function (data) { someFunction(data, '@Url.Action("SomeAction", "SomeController")') }">Action!</button>
```

The syntax highlighting can be suppressed by changing the above to the following:

```
<button data-bind="@("click: function (data) { someFunction(data, '" + Url.Action("SomeAction", "SomeController") + "') }")">Action!</button>
```

Answer (score -4):

Why not just use a regular Html.ActionLink?

```
@Html.ActionLink("Action", "Select", new { destination = Model.Property, entityId = Model.Id });
```